# Windows 7 doesn't recognize USB devices anymore

Tags: windows-7, usb, ipad

So I have a problem with my desktop.
I have an iPad 2 which WAS working fine on my desktop, however, after a week of not connecting it, it suddenly isnt recognized anymore by windows 7.
First I thought it was an Apple issue, but then I disconnected my External hard drive, to find that when reconnecting it again it didnt work anymore with the same problem.
I'm afraid to pull out any other USB devices since they may stop working....

I have done so far:
- Rebooted
- Reinstalled usb drivers
- Have had power off the motherboard/pc for a while.
- Updated windows/drivers.

Any ideas? thx

Comment: You have checked that it is just this computer you're having the issues with right? Can you get any USB device to work in the desktop at all?

Comment: It seems like everything I try to connect now (what is not already connected) doesnt get recognized. Tried Galaxy S4 phone, Ipad2, External harddrives, all things that did work before.
The ubs devices that are plugged in now, and I've not detached (usb keyboard/ network reciever etc) still work fine...

Comment: I would suggest downloading Ubuntu and burning it to a CD. Boot from that and select the try option. Just plug a USB flash drive in (from experience, live CDs sometimes don't like larger external hard drives) and tell us if you can get to the flash drive. Oh, by the way, I'd advise you that now is the perfect time for a backup!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update on my problem, I didnt solve the USB problem but my guess was that it was a hardware issue since I basically ruled out all software issues. 
However, last week, my PC stopped working completely so maybe the USB problem was just the start of the end, and since I was planning in getting some new hardware anyway...thats what I will do.

Answer (score 2):

[USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) will give you a view of what is going on.

> "[USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) is a small utility that lists all USB devices that are
>   currently connected to your computer, as well as all USB devices that
>   you previously used. For each USB device, extended information is
>   displayed: Device name/description, device type, serial number (for
>   mass storage devices), the date/time that device was added, VendorID,
>   ProductID, and more...USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB
>   devices that you previously used, disconnect USB devices that are
>   currently connected to your computer, as well as to disable and enable
>   USB devices. You can also use USBDeview on a remote computer, as long
>   as you login to that computer with admin user."

Comment: I dont see how this can help, besides, the Ipad is not even showing up in the list as Connected.

Comment: I think @packets suggested it so that you could see if your devices were actually being seen by the computer or if it is a lower level problem.

Answer (score 2):

Things I've tried in the past in similar situations that worked:

1. Run [**USB Oblivion**](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/) with the **Do real clean** checkbox checked, then rebooted:

   [image: 1]
2. Deleted all USB root hubs and controllers from **Device Manager**, then rebooted. This is best done with a PS/2 mouse/keyboard connected, since obviously USB devices will stop working.
3. Completely unplugged PC and removed the CMOS battery. Inserted battery after 10-15 mins., powered on, set BIOS options (that have all reverted to defaults) as required, then booted into Windows.

Comment: Ill give it a try, thx :)

Comment: Just did that, didnt work.

Comment: Also just reinstalled windows 7...problem persists.

Comment: Did you try removing the battery? If your devices work fine on other PCs then it seems to be a hardware problem. You can confirm using a Linux LiveCD/USB.

Comment: Just removed the battery, didnt fix it :( The ipad/harddrive works fine on my laptop