# windows 7 recognizes hardware but fails to install drivers

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I recently moved my computer and when I reattached all my usb devices some were working as before and windows tried to install drivers for others. The once it attempted to install drivers for were working at login (like my usb keyboard) but failed as windows could not find a suitable driver for them. It seems to be the case that devices connected to the same usb port before the move still works while those devices that have changed ports do not.

In device manager the devices are listed by name (logitech illuminated keyboard, etc.) but without a functioning driver. I have tried to remove and reinstall and redownload the official logitech drivers. No luck.

This is definitely a windows issue. The keyboard works both in the BIOS menu and in Ubuntu (run from a live cd).

Comment: Try the suggestions mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/619499/138343).

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution to the problem was to simply wait for about a year, after which time Windows was suddenly able to again successfully load the driver for the keyboard.  I had posted a similar (nearly identical) question that went unanswered.  A couple of days ago I found, to my amazement, that the problem had gone away.  What I have suspected all along is that a Windows update caused the original problem, and that a subsequent Windows update fixed it.  Of course there is no way to prove this, and it is obviously not a very practical solution.  But since these questions are remaining unanswered for so long, apparently there are no better solutions.

Curiously, when I posted this as an answer to my own question, a moderated deleted the question as being off topic for this site.  I can't understand how this problem (and the more general and incredibly annoying problem of Windows suddenly and mysteriously not loading drivers for previously working USB devices) is not related to computer hardware or computer software.

Comment: I don't think that's really an answer I would like to give my boss.

Comment: @Kenneth I wholeheartedly agree.  The point of my tongue-in-cheek answer is that there is so little to go on here.  Attention Microsoft Windows USB driver stack maintainers: please throw us a bone!